# Telerik RadEditor doesn't work well on live website

Tags: asp.net-ajax, telerik, radeditor

I'm using a Telerik RadEditor in my Web Project, in localhost editor works well but in the host the style editors(bold, italic etc.) and paragraph selections don't work. How can i solve that problem?

**Update:** (From OP's post, below):

Well here is the screenshot for it, there is htmleditor in radgrid and this time i got this screen. Can't write anything in it because there is no line. I have this problem on development and live server.

[image]

So what can i do for it?

Comment: Is the problem occurring on all browsers or only in certain browsers?

Comment: Is the production site giving any errors in the developer tools (that's for chrome... but use any js debug tool to check)?

Comment: What version of RadControls are you using?

Comment: Please could you use the dev tools (F12 in most modern browsers) and let us know if you're getting any 404 errors for javascript requests on the live site that you don't get on the local?

Answer (score 1):

Can you post details on what doesn't work?  A screenshot would help.

There are some things to look at first:

Make sure your tools file is deployed on your live site.

Right click on your RadEditorTools.xml file and select "Properties".  Then make sure the following are set:

1. "Build Action" = "Content"
2. "Copy to output Directory" = "Copy always"

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-using-toolsfile.html

Comment: in my case the editor is fully functional on a development server, but the javascript malfunctions (with varying degrees across browsers) on the live server.  The only difference in the environments is the trust level

Comment: "The only difference in the environments is the trust level" that's a fairly major difference. I have a 3-part post here if you want to unit test your trust level locally http://boxbinary.com/2011/10/unit-testing-medium-trust-using-nunit-umbraco-5-and-a-dose-of-magic-fancypants-part-one/ If you just want to test, change your `<trust>` element to `level="Medium"` in your local web.config to let us know if you can replicate the issue locally.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still having troubles with this, you should ask on the Telerik forums.

Looking at the screenshot, it seems that the RadEditor content area is not the proper size - it is shrunk down to one line (white rectangle above the Design/HTML/Preview buttons). This can be a browser issue due to an old version of the editor, in which case you need to get a newer version of the RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX that supports this browser. This could also be a CSS issue with some of the styles on your page, in which case you can try switching the content area from iframe to div (ContentAreaMode = "Div" in the  tag) .

Answer (score 0):

Could your browser be using different settings for javascript 
when you browse to localhost or the host?

IE applies different security settings on local or trusted sites?

If you test your site on the host itself via rdp, IE under windows server 2k3 or 2k8
also applies some scipt blocks on javascript, or disables it entirely.

you can check this in your Internet Options - Security - Custom level (on trusted sites or internet sites)

You can also try to add the url to the host machine to the trusted sites.

Comment: no, it's not about ie, all the browsers are with the same result. I posted a new image, how does it look. well ckeditor works fine, but i couldn't add it to grid's edittemplate. can you help me about it?